# Dynamically adding fields to JSF form

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have the following situation that I would like to handle in JSF. My form consists of family information (name/address/phone) and then children information. Since a family can have more then one child, I need to be able to allow the person to click "add more children" and another child "section" will appear.

Here is a simple test case I've thrown together.

Backing Bean. A family has a list of children.

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
public class TestBackingBean implements Serializable {
    private Family f = new Family();
    private Child childToRemove;

    public TestBackingBean() {
        f.addChild(new Child());
    }

    public Family getFamily() {
        return f;
    }

    public void setChildToRemove(Child childToRemove) {
        this.childToRemove = childToRemove;
    }

    public TimeZone getTimezone() {
        return TimeZone.getDefault();
    }

    public List<Child> getChildren() {
        return f.getChildrenAsList();
    }

    public Child getChildToRemove() {
        return childToRemove;
    }

    public void addChild() {
        f.addChild(new Child());
    }

    public void removeChild() {
        f.removeChild(childToRemove);
    }

}
```

Here is the JSF page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title><ui:insert name="title" />
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/hcbb/css/main.css" />
</h:head>

<h:body>

    <h:form>

        <h:panelGroup id="parentSection">
            <h:outputLabel value="Parent Name" for="parent_firstName" />
            <h:inputText id="parent_firstName" requiredMessage="Required"
                immediate="true" label="Parent First Name"
                value="#{testBackingBean.family.firstName}">
                <f:validateRequired />
            </h:inputText>
            <rich:message id="parent_firstNameMessage" for="parent_firstName" />
        </h:panelGroup>


        <h:panelGroup id="childrenSection">

            <h:dataTable value="#{testBackingBean.children}" var="child">

                <h:column>
                    <h:panelGrid id="childPanel" columns="3"
                        style="border:1px solid brown; padding: 5px; margin-bottom:5px; width: 600px;">
                        <h:outputText id="childTitle" value="Child"
                            style="font-weight: bold;" />
                        <h:outputText id="spacer" />
                        <a4j:commandButton id="removeBtn"
                            action="#{testBackingBean.removeChild}" immediate="true"
                            value="Remove Child" render="childrenSection"
                            style="float:right;" title="Remove">
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener
                                target="#{testBackingBean.childToRemove}" value="#{child}" />
                        </a4j:commandButton>

                        <h:outputLabel id="child_firstNameLbl" value="First Name" />
                        <h:inputText id="child_firstName" requiredMessage="Required"
                            immediate="true" label="Child First Name"
                            value="#{child.firstName}">
                            <f:validateRequired />
                        </h:inputText>
                        <rich:message id="child_firstNameMessage" for="child_firstName" />

                        <h:outputLabel id="child_lastNameLbl" value="Last Name" />
                        <h:inputText id="child_lastName" requiredMessage="Required"
                            immediate="true" label="Child Last Name"
                            value="#{child.lastName}">
                            <f:validateRequired />
                        </h:inputText>
                        <rich:message id="child_lastNameMessage" for="child_lastName" />

                        <h:outputLabel id="child_dobLbl" value="Birth Date" />
                        <h:inputText id="child_dob" label="Child Birth Date"
                            immediate="true" requiredMessage="Required"
                            value="#{child.dateOfBirth}">
                            <f:convertDateTime id="dobConverter" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"
                                timeZone="#{testBackingBean.timezone}" />
                            <f:validateRequired />
                        </h:inputText>
                        <rich:message id="child_dobNameMessage" for="child_dob" />
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>

            <a4j:commandLink id="addChildBtn" immediate="true"
                render="childrenSection" action="#{testBackingBean.addChild}"
                value="Add Another Child">
            </a4j:commandLink>

        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

The issue is the saving of the values when adding/removing child sections. If you enter parent name and then child name and date of birth and then click add the fields for the child you just added will disappear? I would have thought that immediate=true on the button and the fields will get them through.

The problem is add a parent first name, enter child info and click the add another child button and the child information you just entered will be erased.

Any suggestions on how I might be able to make this all work. Seems like a fairly simple and somewhat standard use case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks fine at the first glance. The problem symptoms boils down that the `f.getChildrenAsList()` doesn't return a list with the new child while JSF is about to apply request values. Perhaps that method is re-fetching the list from DB again upon submit? Add a breakpoint to investigate its retun value. Or perhaps the view scope failed and caused the bean to be reconstructed? Add a breakpoint to the bean's constructor. It should not be reconstructed when you're submitting the form against the same view.

As to using the `immediate` attribute, all your usage of them is entirely superfluous. Just remove them. To understand its use better, get yourself through the [Debug JSF lifecycle](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html) article (true, it's JSF 1.2 targeted, but the principles are the same for JSF2) and then read particularly this summary:

> ### [Okay, when should I use the immediate attribute?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html#WhenShouldIUseTheImmediateAttribute)
>
> If it isn't entirely clear yet, here's a summary, complete with real world use examples when they may be beneficial:
>
> - If set in `UIInput`(s) only, the process validations phase will be taken place in apply request values phase instead. Use this to prioritize validation for the `UIInput` component(s) in question. When validation/conversion fails for any of them, the non-immediate components won't be validated/converted.
> - If set in `UICommand` only, the apply request values phase until with update model values phases will be skipped for any of the `UIInput` component(s). Use this to skip the entire processing of the form. E.g. "Cancel" or "Back" button.
> - If set in both `UIInput` and `UICommand` components, the apply request values phase until with update model values phases will be skipped for any of the `UIInput` component(s) which does not have this attribute set. Use this to skip the processing of the entire form expect for certain fields (with immediate). E.g. "Password forgotten" button in a login form with a required but non-immediate password field.

Comment: Thanks BalusC. I'll look into that more with the getChildrenAsList. I see your point about the immediate on *everything*

Comment: I think the problem was that the getChildrenAsList() was returning a new ArrayList() each time.