# Disable validation on an ICEFaces form on specific button presses

Tags: java, validation, jsf, icefaces

I have an IceFaces form with several `HtmlCommandButtons` on it. I have some input fields that have attached validators. The validation works well, but runs and blocks the process even if I press buttons different than the submit one. Logical because all my buttons are basically the same. The question is: how to distinguish between the buttons from the aspect of validation?

I cannot provide XHTML snippet because my form is build dynamically from Java code. The buttons are created this way:

```
    HtmlCommandButton comp = new HtmlCommandButton();
    comp.setId("btn" + StringUtil.toId(label) + "_" + action);
    comp.setTitle(label);
    comp.setValue(label);
    comp.setStyleClass("commandexbutton commandexbutton-" + StringUtil.toId(label));
    comp.addActionListener(JSFBuilderHelper.createActionListener(getActionListenerStr()));
    comp.setPartialSubmit(true);
```

Comment: Depends on the purpose of the button. What is the button in question supposed to do?

Comment: That button performs some kind of 'Cancel' operation (closes the form, restores the previous form from the form-stack, broadcasts messages in the application, and so on..)

Comment: OK, straightforward enough, I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At simplest, you could set the `UICommand` component's `immediate` attribute to `true`. It will then skip the processing of `UIInput` components which does **not** have this attribute to `true`.

```
comp.setImmediate(true);
```

For a detailed explanation of the usage of this attribute, see the 2nd half of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7274511/157882).

If that's not an option, then your best bet is to put the cancel button in a separate form so that it effectively ends up like:

```html
<h:form>
    input fields 
    submit button
</h:form>
<h:form>
    cancel button
</h:form>
```

If that's also not an option due to design/layout restrictions (read: not fixable by just CSS/JS), then you basically need to check in every validator which button is been pressed. You could check that by the presence of the button's client name (ID) in the request parameter map. For example, as component's attribute:

```html
required="#{not empty param['formId:submitButtonId']}"
```

or

```html
required="#{empty param['formId:cancelButtonId']}"
```

or in the beginning of the validator's `validate()` method:

```
if (externalContext.getRequestParameterMap().get("formId:submitButtonId") == null) {
    return; // Skip validation when normal submit button is not pressed.
}
```

or

```
if (externalContext.getRequestParameterMap().get("formId:cancelButtonId") != null) {
    return; // Skip validation when cancel button is pressed.
}
```

Comment: I would like to mix immediate and not immediate components on the form. If I set the backButton's immediate to true, then it will still validate those components.. Can this be solved too..?

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately that gets more complicated. Simplest approach would be to put the button in a separate (not nested!) form. Is that possible for you? If not, then you need to tell what kind of validation you'd like to skip. Just the `required` validation? Or also all other (custom) validators?

Comment: Nested form sounds little hard. I added a validator to my input field like this: `textbox.addValidator(new RegExpValidator(validatorExpr));`

Comment: No, not nested, just separate. So that you effectively end up with `<h:form>normal inputs + submit button</h:form><h:form>cancel button</h:form>`.

Comment: I see.. Well, then what about the "if not, then you need to tell what kind of validation you'd like to skip" possibility? You made me curious. (However I think this nested form thing will do now.)

Comment: You could check the presence of the button's client name (ID) in the request parameter map inside the validator. But you have to do it for every validator, also the `required` one. E.g. `required="#{not empty param['formid:submitbuttonid']}"`.

Comment: so cool! i have a common CompositeValidator that calls other validators sequentially, so this could be done at one, common place! :-)

Comment: Oh, that's then already designed nicely from the beginning on. Good work! :)