# Dynamically adding fields to JSF form on button click

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Did you find any solution for this problem. I am using JSF 2.0 with CDI and I am facing the same issue while adding multiple previous addresses on click of a button "Add Previous Address".

I am able to add and update other fields but not the fields added in the list of h:dataTable using the above approach.

[Dynamically adding fields to JSF form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274125/dynamically-adding-fields-to-jsf-form/7274511#7274511)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc

Comment: Advice for the next question: elaborate "doesn't work" in developer's perspective, not in enduser's perspective. This is a Q&A site for web developers, not a helpdesk forum for web endusers. See also [ask].